# Account.AccountTeamMembers not visible to end users but visible to admins

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, account-teams

Does anyone know why the following query would return 0 AccountTeamMember records when run as a user, but returns the expected number of records when run as an admin (i.e., myself)?

```
SELECT Id,
    (
        SELECT Id, TeamMemberRole, UserId
        FROM AccountTeamMembers
        WHERE TeamMemberRole = :DEFAULT_TEAM_MEMBER_ROLE
    )
FROM Account
```

The odd behavior is occurring in the trigger that executes when the Account Owner is changed. When an end user tries to transfer an account to a different user, the query above returns 0 records. But when I attempt the same transfer, the query above returns the expected number of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a utility class to perform the query, make sure it is running "without sharing".

Comment: This "resolved" the error for me, but I still don't understand why. The kicker is that as the end user, I could see the full account team both before _and_ after transferring ownership. So, if the user could explicitly see the team in the UI, I wonder: Why would the user not be able to "see" the team in Apex, even with sharing rules enforced?

Comment: @MartyC. That is curious, actually. If they saw it in the UI, they should also be able to see it through code, I suppose. I'll have to experiment with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to Sharing security settings, like sfdcfox is getting at.  Take a look at your OWD and sharing rules for Account.  Either you'll need to use without sharing like sfdcfox mentioned, or you'll need to reconsider your sharing settings, or perhaps the data is even coming back as you would expect.